# Newton-Gauss line proof in L. Brand's "Vector and Tensor Analysis"

Tags: geometry, reference-request, vectors

I refer to [this book](https://books.google.cl/books?id=ZYS4AAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Does anybody has a more intelligible way of explaining what the author means with "static addition" of vectors, or how does addition of line vectors is defined when they are collinear?

How can we define in a more comprehensible way the "statically equal to zero" assertion? For example, this theorem is already cryptic to me (page 10)

[image: 1]

The aforementioned Newton-Gauss line proof is below (page 11). It looks impressively simple, but I cannot say I really comprehend it. Can anyone point me to references or perhaps an equivalent but more modern approach to these ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The statical addition of vectors is defined on page 2 in the text as the addition of line vectors. It's named after [statical equivalence](https://www.ae.msstate.edu/vlsm/non_con_force/force_equiv/force_equiv.htm) in engineering which is hinted at on the text when they mention rigid body problems. So it's just vector addition as usual with the understanding that the vectors involved are defined by the points in question.

Statical equality to zero just means they add up to zero and it's almost obvious for colinear points. Placing $B$ on the line between $A$ and $C$ shows is that $\vec{AB} + \vec{BC}=\vec{AC}$ and since $\vec{AC} = -\vec{CA}$ we have $\vec{AB} + \vec{BC} + \vec{CA}=0$. This idea is used repeatedly in the example.

For the prove given in example the important quality is that the midpoint between line vectors $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$ is $\frac12(\vec{AB}+\vec{AC})$ and that how the equations for $\vec{AQ}, \vec{CQ}$ and $\vec{QP}$ are derived. The other midpoints are defined accordingly and most of the proof is then bookkeeping to ensure the right terms cancel. Don't let the language trip you up though, this all just vector arithmetic as usual.

Comment: Thank you. I still do not see why $\vec{AB}+\vec{BC}+\vec{CA}$ would not be zero even if the points are not collinear. I think this is not just a language thing, it is important for the proof since it is the criterion for collinearity used in the conclusion of the proof.